# mutate() returns error of 'Object not found'

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to clean and add a new column to my data named `Volume` using `mutate()`.

This is the data that I have read into R:

```
> df1 <- file.choose()
> data1 <- read_excel(df1)                                                                                                                                   
> head(data1)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  `product id` amount `total sales`
  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 X180             20           200
2 X109             30           300
3 X918             20           200
4 X273             15           150
5 X988             12           120
```

Next, I subset and renamed the columns `product id` and `total sales` to `Product Code` and `Net Sales` respectively, and applied `mutate()` with my own function on `Net Sales` and created a new `Volume` column.

```
> data2 <- data1 %>% 
+   select(`Product Code` = `product id`, `Net Sales` = `total sales`) %>%
+   replace_na(list(`Net Sales` = 0))%>%
+   arrange(desc(`Net Sales`))%>%
+   mutate(Volume = rank_volume(data1, `Net Sales`))
```

This is the error message I get:

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Volume`.
ℹ `Volume = rank_volume(data1, `Net Sales`)`.
x arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
* Problem with `mutate()` column `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = Net Sales`.
x object 'Net Sales' not found
```

And here is the function `rank_volume` i created

```
### a function to label the products that are top one third in total sales as "H", products with the lowest third in sales as "L", and the rest as "M"
rank_volume <- function(data, column) {
  
  column <- ensym(column)
  colstr <- as_string(column)
  data <- arrange(data, desc(!!column))
  size <- length(data[[colstr]])
  first_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size / 3)]
  last_third <- data[[colstr]][round(size - (size / 3))]
  
  case_when(data[[colstr]] > first_third ~ "H",
            data[[colstr]] < last_third ~ "L",
            TRUE ~ "M")
}
```

When I run my function separately with a simple data frame, it works perfectly. However, when I run it with mutate() the error appeared. I couldn't find the problem. Can anyone help?

EDIT: `dput(head(data))`

```
> dput(head(data1))
structure(list(`product id` = c("X180", "X109", "X918", "X273", 
"X988"), amount = c(20, 30, 20, 15, 12), `total sales` = c(200, 
300, 200, 150, 120)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible piece of your data by means of `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: You are calling data1 in your mutate while data1 has no Net Sales column

Comment: @BastienDucreux I had changed the name of total sales to Net Sales in my cleanup. Does `mutate()` takes the initial data1 instead? It works when I changed it to ```mutate(Volume = rank_volume(data1, `total sales`))```

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I have added `dput(head(data))` in the EDIT now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data1` does not have `Net Sales` column, it is present in the transformation that you have done. You can use `.` to refer to current dataframe in pipe.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>% 
     select(`Product Code` = `product id`, `Net Sales` = `total sales`) %>%
     replace_na(list(`Net Sales` = 0))%>%
     arrange(desc(`Net Sales`)) %>%
     mutate(Volume = rank_volume(., `Net Sales`))

# `Product Code` `Net Sales` Volume
#  <chr>                <dbl> <chr> 
#1 X109                   300 H     
#2 X180                   200 M     
#3 X918                   200 M     
#4 X273                   150 L     
#5 X988                   120 L
```

Or can also use `cur_data()` -

```
data1 %>% 
     select(`Product Code` = `product id`, `Net Sales` = `total sales`) %>%
     replace_na(list(`Net Sales` = 0))%>%
     arrange(desc(`Net Sales`)) %>%
     mutate(Volume = rank_volume(cur_data(), `Net Sales`))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the new column after you've done the initial clean up.

```r
  data2 <- data1 %>% 
  select("Product Code" = "product id", "Net Sales" = "total sales") %>%
  replace_na(list("Net Sales" = 0))%>%
  arrange(desc("Net Sales"))
  
  data2 <- data2 %>%
  mutate(Volume = rank_volume(data2, "Net Sales"))
```